Implement object counting after tracking
Open video with OpenCV
I want to improve my object tracking algorithm to be counting object whenever the vehicle across the restrict line and do not want a duplicate data also and here the result of my detection
Detections(xyxy=array([[342.3293  , 335.03476 , 465.3704  , 427.93594 ],
       [122.26098 , 531.9414  , 263.60587 , 574.8308  ],
       [209.58714 , 167.03366 , 405.6145  , 365.10098 ],
       [ 21.653362, 405.5883  , 167.43967 , 511.19382 ]], dtype=float32), confidence=array([0.72265625, 0.7578125 , 0.70703125, 0.60546875], dtype=float32),

import os
import cv2

from dotenv import load_dotenv
from base_camera import BaseCamera
from detector import Detector
from utils import visualize
from detection import Detections
from tracker.byte_track.core import ByteTrack


load_dotenv(".env")


class Camera(BaseCamera):
    """
    OpenCV video stream
    """
    video_source = 0
    detector = Detector()
    tracker = ByteTrack()

    def __init__(self, enable_detection: bool = False):
        video_source = os.environ.get("VIDEO_SOURCE")
        try:
            video_source = int(video_source)
        except Exception as exp:    # pylint: disable=broad-except
            if not video_source:
                raise EnvironmentError("Cannot open the video source!") from exp
        finally:
            Camera.set_video_source(video_source)
        super().__init__()
        self.enable_detection = enable_detection

    @staticmethod
    def set_video_source(source):
        """Set video source"""
        Camera.video_source = source

    @classmethod
    def frames(cls):
        """
        Get video frame
        """
        camera = cv2.VideoCapture(Camera.video_source)
        
        if not camera.isOpened():
            raise RuntimeError("Could not start camera.")

        while True:
            # read current frame
            ret, img = camera.read()

            # Loop back
            if not ret:
                camera.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_POS_FRAMES, 0)
                continue

            # Object detection
            results = cls.detector(image=img)

            tensorflow_results = results.detections

            if not tensorflow_results:
                yield cv2.imencode(".jpg", img)[1].tobytes()
                continue

            detections = Detections.from_tensorflow(tensorflow_results=tensorflow_results)

            detections = cls.tracker.update_with_detections(detections=detections)
            # print(detections)
            restrict_line=((100,300),(500,550))

            img = visualize(image=img, detections=detections)
            count=0
            
            cv2.line(img, restrict_line[0], restrict_line[1], (255, 0, 0), 5)
                        # Check if any detected object crosses the restrict line
            

            
            # encode as a jpeg image and return it
            yield cv2.imencode(".jpg", img)[1].tobytes()


I want to improve my code

What language is this? Perhaps a language tag would be useful?

You also haven't asked a question. Perhaps you should read [ask]?
